# Does the Cakephp Media plugin work with Cakephp 2.0?

Tags: cakephp, plugins

```
Does the Cakephp Media plugin work with Cakephp 2.0 ?
```

I have just downloaded the Media plugin and I don't know whether it works or not with Cakephp 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Cakephp Media plugin are you referring to? If it is this one: https://github.com/davidpersson/media then the answer would be no as stated in the readme. If you are referring to a different one, then please add the link.

**UPDATE**

Here is a behavior that may be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/jrbasso/MeioUpload

Comment: Yes I mean DavidPersson's ...it doesn't work on 2.0? oh thank God bro, i was about to start working on that. So what should I do? I need to handle file uploads quick, but i just want a download, write 3 lines of code and voila kind of approach...you know

Comment: Write an upload behavior. It's fairly easy to do and a slick way to do it. It's not 3 lines of code, but it works great and is reusable. Or you can use the Meio Upload. I use my own behavior but this is a common one. See the update in the answer for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this fork on cake2 :
https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin